# Maximum message rate to and from Firebase database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, messaging

I can't find documentation on best practices for the maximum number of messages one should send to the Firebase database (or one like it) over a period of time, like one second, and also what rate an app could handle receiving without slowing down significantly. For example:

```
//send updated location of user character in MMORG
MyDatabaseReference.child(LOCATIONS).child(charid).setValue . . .

//recieive locations of other characters in a MMORG
MyDatabaseReference.child(LOCATIONS).addValueEventListener(new 
ValueEventListener() { . . .
```

In testing, 3 devices each sending 20 messages per second to the database, and each receiving 60 messages per second, appears to work OK (S8 used, a fast device). I was wondering what would happen with, say, 100 devices, in which case each user app would be getting 2000 messages per second theoretically. I imagine there is some automatic throttling of this.

Comment: See https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/usage/limits

Answer (score 1):

As mentioned in Firebase officil documentation regarding Firebase database limits, there is a maximum of `1000 write operations/second` for the free plan.

If you want to stay on the free plan, remember that when you'll reach the maximum number of writes per second, it doesn't mean that you'll not be able to use Firebase database anymore. When 1001th simultaneous connection occurs, a queue of operations is created and Firebase will wait until one connection is closed, and than it uses your new connection.